# Mahapps.Metro dark theme not showing in designer

Tags: mahapps.metro

I am using MahApps.Metro version 1.2.0.0.  I have set my theme to a Dark theme.  This works fine when I run the application but still shows the light theme in my designer.

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseDark.xaml" />
```

Thoughts on what is causing this issue?

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you look closely, neither Dark nor Light themes are applied at design time.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. The issue is that it does load the themes, for example the white text, correctly (at some point, initially it doesn't seem to). But it doesn't load the background, so the white text becomes invisible - kind of defeats the point of the designer.

Answer (score 3):

I found that in XAML designer:

- The window title bar is never styled
- After restarting Visual Studio, the components *seem* to be styled...
- ...except for MetroWindow's background, which shows as white.

So, many components are white-on-white (invisible!) in the designer. I've been working around it, as follows.

For MetroWindows, I set the background of each to reference the theme color:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow
    ....
    Background="{DynamicResource WindowBackgroundBrush}">
```

For user controls and pages, rather than set the background on every one, you can leave it transparent and set the designer to have a dark background. Then they show up well enough for designing:

[image]

It's a bodge, but its what I've been working with.

Comment: Updated question with the solution I've been using. Only tried it with the blue highlights theme though, and dark background.

Comment: I [chatted with](https://gitter.im/MahApps/MahApps.Metro?at=59dfe9f8f7299e8f53ddff03) a MahApps author, and looks like XAML designer has a bug/limitation showing subclasses of Window, e.g. MetroWindow. I tried subclassing Window myself, and can't find any way to get background color to show in XAML designer (tried setting it in C#, XAML, or Themes\Generic.cs). Joe's workaround seems to be the way to go.